# Resume an application's state after locale change

Tags: android, state

i have a simple radio app for android. everything is ok, but there're 2 locale in it (russian & english) and while the app is runnig and after I switch from one locale to another one on my device and press app icon again, is start with new state, the title name is not changing and STOP and PLAY buttons not working. how i can fix it?

P.S. sorry for my language skills

Comment: Do you have `android:configChanges` in your manifest for any of your `<activity>` elements? If yes, either get rid of them or ensure you update your various strings yourself.

Comment: yes, i have android:configChanges with locale and orientation params inited. but the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

> i have android:configChanges with locale and orientation params inited.

Either:

- Delete that, and use a better approach for handling configuration changes, or
- You have to write code in `onConfigurationChanged()` to fix your problem, by adjusting the "title name" and "STOP and PLAY buttons"

Comment: i have an online stream in my app, and if i recreate everything in onConfigurationChanged() there'll be the second stream with audio

Comment: @JackDaniel: I did not tell you to "recreate everything in onConfigurationChanged()". You are welcome to do things like call `setText()` on your buttons, for example.

Comment: the text issues workig normal, but how i can recreate the AsyncTask for getting audio title and button actions